# Ubuntu web server unable to connect to web but still serves pages

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, web-server, ubuntu-11.10

I have been running our website on an ubuntu server for the last few months and all has been going well.  However today the server will not allow connections externally so I cannot update wordpress plugins or even browse the internet.

The site is still functioning perfectly. How do I start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

Could be DNS.

Check your resolv.conf, try "dig something.com @whatever-you-have-in-your-resolv-conf" and see if you get reply.

You can always put there google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Alternatively try to ping or traceroute some external ip (but that does not seems to be your case).